# Why is PYTHONPATH being ignored?

Tags: python

I am setting PYTHONPATH to have a directory that includes a few .py files.

When I go into python and type "import file", the file cannot be find (it says "No module named wsj10").

If, however, I cd to the directory, and repeat the same process, then the file is found.

I am just not sure why PYTHONPATH is being ignored. I followed exact instructions from installation instructions of some software, so I know I am doing the right thing.

Any circumstances under which PYTHONPATH will be ignored, or import won't work?

Thanks.

Following a comment below, here is a transcript:

1. untar file1.tgz to file1/. file1.tgz contains a library/file called file1.py.
2. type in the shell:

   ```
   export PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/file1/:./
   ```
3. `echo $PYTHONPATH` shows the variable was set.
4. run python and type "import file1"

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named file1
```

If I do first "cd file1" and then to import file1 it identifies the file.

Comment: Show us a transcript of exactly what you are running.

Comment: is PYTHONPATH exported?

Comment: @suspectus yes, it is. John, I added that transcript.

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` file in the directory?

Comment: @Burhan, there is a setup.py, but not __init__.py.

Comment: Run `python setup.py install` first.

Comment: @Burhan, does not help. and also, that step does not seem to be required by the README.

Comment: What is this package you are trying to use?

Comment: It is a certain piece of code that someone provided me. I am pretty sure people have used it in the past.

Comment: What does `import sys; print sys.path` say?

Answer (score 1):

> Any circumstances under which PYTHONPATH will be ignored, or import won't work?

Yes. I've set PYTHONPATH in my /home/me/.bashrc and all worked ok from terminal, but when Apache w/ mod_wsgi starts my python scripts, it acts under sysem or dedicated user, which knows nothing of my .bashrc.

For this particular situation, I just used apache config to set python path for apache (WSGIPythonPath option).

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue right now but I don't know apache very well. Can you tell me how you set the python path for apache?

Comment: Apache probably runs as a difference user so it will not source your `.bashrc`. This means that `PYTHONPATH` *is not set* -- that is not the same thing as *it is ignored* .