# Why are modules in PYTHONPATH not found when the containing directory is part of PYTHONPATH and file exists?

Tags: python, environment-variables, sudo, environment

I have the following situation (verfication through commands below):

- existing python script file in directory x
- existing python cat `__init__.py` file in x
- x added to `PYTHONPATH` variable availble for both logged in user and `sudo`

and I want to invoke `~/test.py` with

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys;print sys.path;
import mount_utils
print "Hello World!"
```

with `sudo python ~/test.py` which causes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/richter/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mount_utils
ImportError: No module named mount_utils
```

the directories in `PYTHONPATH` are not in `sys.path` except the current directory. `python ~/test.py` works as expected (prints `sys.path` and `Hello World!` to console). `sudo -E python ~/test.py` fails with the same error. I don't understand

- Why the module isn't availble if `PYTHONPATH` variable is printed in `sudo echo` output
- Why `sudo -E` doesn't preserve the environment (as far as I understand from `man sudo` and https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html there shouldn't be any difference between `python bla` and `sudo -E python bla`)

Why do I get this error?

Verification of situation in detail:

```
$ env | grep PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=:/home/richter/scripts/python:/home/richter/scripts/python/installsystem:/home/richter/scripts/python/lib
$ sudo env | grep PYTHONPATH
$ LANG=C stat /home/richter/scripts/python/lib/mount_utils.py
  File: '/home/richter/scripts/python/lib/mount_utils.py'
  Size: 8374        Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 80ch/2060d  Inode: 20972052    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ richter)   Gid: ( 1000/ richter)
Access: 2014-08-19 17:06:37.542787417 +0200
Modify: 2014-07-31 10:54:14.709468668 +0200
Change: 2014-07-31 10:54:14.729478917 +0200
 Birth: -
$ LANG=C stat /home/richter/scripts/python/lib/__init__.py
  File: '/home/richter/scripts/python/lib/__init__.py'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 80ch/2060d  Inode: 20972114    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ richter)   Gid: ( 1000/ richter)
Access: 2014-08-09 19:49:44.345055332 +0200
Modify: 2014-05-07 06:57:31.434851243 +0200
Change: 2014-06-25 03:17:29.569551147 +0200
 Birth: -
```

I didn't get any idea from the quite similar unanswered question [Why is PYTHONPATH being ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461452/why-is-pythonpath-being-ignored)

**EDIT 1:** After considering [How to set environment variable for everyone under my linux system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641477/how-to-set-environment-variable-for-everyone-under-my-linux-system) and the fact that `echo ...` is a rather bad way to ensure whether env variables are set, I put `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/home/richter/scripts/python:/home/richter/scripts/python/installsystem:/home/richter/scripts/python/lib"` in

- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/profile.d/python_py.sh`
- `/root/.bashrc`
- `/home/richter/.bashrc`

and now `PYTHONPATH` is (in addition to situation described above) available in `env` in `sudo -i` prompt, but not in `sudo env | grep PYTHONPATH`. `sudo python test.py` still fails due to the same error, i.e. my problems remains.

Also `export PYTHONPATH="/home/richter/scripts/python:/home/richter/scripts/python/installsystem:/home/richter/scripts/python/lib" && sudo -E python test.py` fails due to the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to the sudoers `env_keep`.

Run:
`sudo visudo` (which opens the `/etc/sudoers` file in a safe way).

Add this line:
`Defaults    env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"`.

Now `:wq`, and that will preserve the `PYTHONPATH` variable when running `sudo`

Comment: How do I do this in Windows? I am stuck while running unit tests. I am getting error `Importing test modules ... PYTHONPATH not found for file: ...`. I have asked the detailed question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52593584/6357916)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the environment sudo is running under (root's) does not have the `PYTHONPATH` set?

```
sudo echo $PYTHONPATH
```

For this command, I think shell interpolation is hitting it before `sudo` executes so you are in essence just writing

```
sudo echo /home/richter/scripts/python:/home/richter/scripts/python/installsystem:/home/richter/scripts/python/lib
```

which is really no different to

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

I can see you may be thinking along those lines with `sudo -E`  (though I could not see  specific output for that in your examples) - I don't personally have experience with `sudo -E`.

You could try

```
sudo 'echo $PYTHONPATH'
```

Where single quotes stop interpolation, and also

```
sudo -E 'echo $PYTHONPATH'
```

just in case when you are using `sudo -E` it is really just hitting the shell interpolation issue again...

//these suggestions are off top of my head, your mileage may vary!

Comment: almost... `sudo 'echo $PYTHONPATH'` doesn't work, but in prompt of `sudo -i` I see that `echo $PYTHONPATH` is empty. Thanks for your input.