# Python unit tests are not running at all

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-unittest

I am first time trying out python unit tests referring to [this article](https://wwken.wordpress.com/2014/11/18/tutorial-python-unit-test-with-eclipse-1/). I have PyDev plugin installed in my Eclipse.

My `test_hello.py` looks like this:

```
import unittest

class TestHello(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_abc(self):
        print("Test!!!")
        result = True
        self.assertEqual(result, True, "ohno")
```

When I `Right click on source > Run As > Python unit-test`, it outputs:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... PYTHONPATH not found for file: D:\workspaces\python-ws\test\test_h
done.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Also in PyUnit tab, it doesnt show anything:

[image]

What I am missing here?

**Update**

Adding more details:

My project:

[image]

PyDev package explorer

[image]

Comment: you define the test, but it doesn't look like you are calling your function - therefore, nothing is executed

Comment: I just tried by adding `a = TestHello()` and `a.test_abc() ` at the end. Still no use.

Comment: Also am I supposed to do that? In java unit test we just annotate with `@Test` and it works. Also the stated article doesnt seem to do that either...

Comment: not sure, I have never used this module before - maybe someone else can help

Comment: did u used any other for unit tests?

Comment: nope, my testing routine is normally just changing the code and looking if it works....not advisable though

Comment: It looks to me like your setup is not right.  It says it can't find `PYTONPATH`. Check your configuration for eclipse to verify that it is configured properly.

Comment: This might help http://www.pydev.org/faq.html

Comment: ohh could that be an issue...eclipse was shouting that to me for ages now...but my python scripts were always running

Comment: What is python path? Is it where my python resides? Referring [this guide](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html). Is it same as path of interpreters I have added?

Comment: i had a similar problem. Restarting eclipse seemed to fix the problem as a subsequent run as unittest ran the test case.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have probably not configured which path in your project should be in the `PYTHONPATH`.

In PyDev terms, this is the source folder for a project.

You should be able to right-click a folder and select `PyDev > Set as Source Folder (add to PYTHONPATH)` to add that folder to the `PYTHONPATH`.

There's a better description at: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html

Also, make sure that you take a look at the getting started guide: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html

If you still can't have it working, please post a screenshot of your `PyDev Package Explorer`.

Comment: I guess I has the necessary directories added to `PYTHONPATH`. I just created new clean project to fiddle with pydev unit test cases. But I am still getting same error. I have added the screenshots to the original question. Can you check once?

Comment: [...continued] I guess I should be trying out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27605646/6357916). But it answers in the context of linux, which I am not able to get.

Comment: You should usually not have nested source folders (i.e.: leave only `${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}/Test`) as a source folder and see if it fixes -- if that's what you want -- if you want to have only `${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}` try adding a `__init__.py` file inside the `Test` directory.

Comment: I tried by removing `/${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}`  from source folder list. Still getting the same behavior. I found post asking for "why PYTHONPATH not found when the containing directory is part of PYTHONPATH and file exists". But the [answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27605646/6357916) seems very linux specific. Can this resolve my issue. Also can this be something related?

Comment: Ohhh my project was pointing to python installed on cygwin. I changed to project's python interpreter to point to python installed directly on Windows, and it all started working!!! Why is this so?

Comment: Oh, that explains things... cygwin sees paths in one way and Eclipse/PyDev itself in another way, and that mix doesn't work well in practice.

Comment: But is there absolutely no way to make pyunit test cases work? I have some weird stuff going on here. I am using python logger and its debug logs only appear in log files when I am pointing to cygwin python. And when I switch to windows python, those debugs logs do not appear. And now pyunit test cases work on windows python, but not in cygwin python :\

Comment: Unfortunately no, using the python from cygwin is not well supported (if you want to use Linux, then you're expected to do all on Linux). Regarding logging not working, that's probably a different issue (it should definitely work on Python regardless of the platform). Also, if I can suggest something I highly recommend using `pytest` instead of the `unittest` module (note that you have to configure PyDev to use the `pytest` runner in this case: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html).